# How can I take 1000s of photos with my iPhone, storing them directly on my Mac HDD?

Tags: iphone, photos, camera

I understand it's possible to capture photos using an iPhone and store them directly on the Mac's HDD using continuity capture. (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209037)

I have 1000s of collectors cards that I want to photograph. I intend to build a small phone stand and lighting rig. I want the image capture to be as quick as possible: slide the card into place, press a button to capture the image, add some metadata, move onto the next.

I've tried out continuity capture in the notes app but the process involves too many steps: two mouse clicks, a couple of taps on the phone screen, etc...

How can I accomplish this (be it a process, be it an app) easily (Ideally by controlling my phones camera directly from the Mac and saving the photographs straight to the Mac's HDD)?

Comment: Can't you just enable iCloud Photo Syncing and then take the shots from your phone (it's basically one tap per card then)?

Comment: I don't have the extra room on my phone for 1000s of more photos.

Comment: You can set Photos on iOS to optimize storage. It will upload the full-quality picture to iCloud then and just keep a low-res version locally.

Comment: As your question starts to collect downvotes: Can you maybe edit to to focus on the actual objective (take 1000 pictures and transfer to Mac easily) and list the constraints and what you have tried so far? And then ask for ideas on how to solve it, *without* asking for specific software?

Comment: It is better if you edit the "the best" part of the title of your question as it is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: What phone do you have? This will not aid you in your current quest, but it may help you avoid common mistakes when photographing documents/photos/paintings etc. You must 1) illuminate from the sides to prevent reflection & more importantly 2) shoot on a long lens to avoid distortion. <- this will depend on what phone you have. All but the recent high-end iPhones *do not* have lenses suitable for this task. A late 3) Don't shoot on automatic. You need to be able to set the focus, aperture, exposure time & white balance manually, for consistency.

Comment: Enable Photo Sync of the Photo.photolibrary. Assuming the Image is on your Hard Disk